# why we need to design Abstract Factory pattern if we can create direct object at client side?

Tags: .net, abstract-factory

I faced this question while my recent interview. I googled it but except "This is creational pattern and we can create centralized objects" this answer I could not conclude. As i explained this then he asked me but "what is we can create object directly in client classes for server classes. Why should i use abstract factory ?"

Comment: Take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern. Basically the client can use the generic interface to use the object, without ever caring about the actual object created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As NoviceProgrammer said, using the [Abstract Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) design pattern means that the client using the result object, remains independent of the actual result object, as it knows only its interface. Therefore, when a new object type needs to be produced by the Factory side, the client won't have to change a thing in order to handle it, as long as the interface remains the same.

Regarding the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern) example, imagine that you need to add a "LinuxButton" class, to be used by your application. Then you would create another factory, named "LinuxFactory" implementing the generic "GUIFactory" interface. This way, the "Application" class, **does not need to change anything** in order to use the new concrete implementation of "LinuxButton". The factory is the one doing all the job, and the "Application" needs no changes. Now imagine scaling this to hundreds of classes and you will see the value of it.

Hope I helped!